# How to pass data from mysql database to $_SESSOIN

Tags: php, mysql, session

Hello Everyone I am new in PHP and I am trying to create a very small application in php 
I am trying to access the userid of a user using session in php for this I am following these steps

I create these classes in my application

My first class is Database Manager which I place in model folder

```
public function executeQuery($query) {
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if ($result === false) {
            $this->closeConnection($this->conn);
            exit;
        }
            // extract data from results, returning an associative array
            $rows = Array();
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {         
                $rows[] = $row;
            }
            return $rows;
}
```

and then I create these two classes

First is loginManager

```
class LoginManager
{

    function checkLogin($arr)
    {
        require_once(FRONT_ROOT_PATH.'DatabaseManager.php');
        $query ="Select * from tbusers where username='".$arr['username']."' and password='".$arr['password']."'";
        $db= new DatabaseManager();
        $result=$db->executeQuery($query);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

and second is LoginInit

```
<?php
session_start();
include(LIB_PATH."Login/LoginManager.php");

    if(isset($_POST['addlogin']))
    {
        $obj= new LoginManager();
        $userlist=$obj->checkLogin($_POST);
    if(Count($userlist)>0)
    {   
       $_SESSION['uid']=$userlist['userid'];
        header('location:/ProjectDream/view/home/home.php');
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "Login Failed";
    }
    }
}
```

In this class I add the session and after that I call these classes on this php page

```
<?php
include('Include/config.inc.php');
include(LIB_PATH."Login/Logininit.php");

?>
<html>

<head>


    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <title>Login</title>

    <!-- CSS -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

</head>

    <!-- Main HTML -->

<body>

    <!-- Begin Page Content -->

    <div id="container">

    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="addlogin"/>
        <label for="name">Username:</label>

        <input type="name" name="username">

        <label for="username">Password:</label>

        <p><a href="#">Forgot your password?</a>

        <input type="password" name="password">

        <div id="lower">

        <input type="checkbox"><label class="check" for="checkbox">Keep me logged in</label>

        <input type="submit" value="Login">

        </div>

        </form>

    </div>


    <!-- End Page Content -->

</body>

</html>
```

and when user login I send user to home.php page I write this code on home.php

```
<?php

    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['uid'])) 
    {

        echo  $_SESSION['uid'];
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "No Session ";
    }
?>
```

Now when I run this application then it show me no value in my $_SESSION variable 
Is it possible to call session on class level in php. Please tell me how can I use session here 
Thanks

Comment: where you have assign value for $_SESSION['uid']?

Comment: check my loginmanager class in my code i am getting it from there @Ashish

Comment: you're not setting any $_SESSION variable anywhere in your code, you're trying to get values from it, but not putting any value into it

Comment: after successful execution of query in class LoginManager you need to assign it..

Comment: @CodeBird I correct it and after that i am not getting anything

Comment: @Azadchouhan please update the code, so that we can see what's going on. Are you sure your query is returning a result?

Comment: If you are new to PHP and you are writing a new app from scratch you should not bother learning the legacy mysql extension, which already triggers *deprecated* warnings in current PHP version. It's just a waste of time.

Comment: @CodeBird yes it is returning me result and check my question i update it

Comment: @Azadchouhan check my answer, it should solve your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it like this it should work:

```
   $_SESSION['uid']=$userlist[0]['userid'];
```

In your code:

```
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {         
         $rows[] = $row;
     }
```

You are adding `$row` to `$rows` so you're having `$rows[0]=$row`; then `$rows[1]=$row`;

so actually `$rows['userid']` isn't set, it is `$rows[0]['userid']` that is set

Answer (score 0):

the varible to which the value is assigned should be in left side of equation.
so
change

```
$userlist['userid']=$_SESSION['uid'];
```

to

```
$_SESSION['uid']=$userlist['userid'];
```

Comment: where you are using this $_SESSION['uid'] ?

Answer (score 0):

You must assign some value to `$_SESSION['uid']` when reading values from database. Something like:

```
$_SESSION['uid'] = $row['uid'];
```

Also note that when you want to use data from `$_SESSION` variable you must call `session_start()`.